# While checking whether the user and password exists in the database “The entity type User is not part of the model for the current context”

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

While checking whether the user exists in the database, this happens "The entity type User is not part of the model for the current context".

The database located on a remote server. Maybe it's because of her?

"Sorry for my bad english"

This my Context:

```
public class UserContext : DbContext
{

    public UserContext() :
    base("PracticeDB")
    {

    }
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<User>().ToTable("Users");
    }
    public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
}
```

View model:

```
 namespace Models.Models
{
    public class LoginModel
    {
        [Required]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [DataType(DataType.Password)]
        public string Password { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Controller:

```
namespace Models.Controllers
{
    public class AccountController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Login()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Login(LoginModel model)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                User user = null;
                using (UserContext db = new UserContext())
                {
                    user = db.Users.FirstOrDefault(u => u.Name == model.Name && u.Password == model.Password);

                }
                if (user != null)
                {
                    FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(model.Name, true);
                    return RedirectToAction("Users");
                }
                else
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError("", "Пользователя с таким логином и паролем нет");
                }
            }

            return View(model);
        }

    }
}
```

Error:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oUQm2.png)

Breakpoint:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wvj7o.png)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
  Дополнительные сведения о настройке приложения ASP.NET см. по адресу:
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301880
  -->
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
  </configSections>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Version" value="3.0.0.0" />
    <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
    <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms name="cookies" timeout="2880" loginUrl="~/Account/Login" />
    </authentication>
  </system.web>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Helpers" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-5.2.3.0" newVersion="5.2.3.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
  <system.codedom>
    <compilers>
      <compiler language="c#;cs;csharp" extension=".cs" type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.CSharpCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:6 /nowarn:1659;1699;1701" />
      <compiler language="vb;vbs;visualbasic;vbscript" extension=".vb" type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.VBCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:14 /nowarn:41008 /define:_MYTYPE=\&quot;Web\&quot; /optionInfer+" />
    </compilers>
  </system.codedom>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="PracticeDB" connectionString="metadata=res://*/DataBase.csdl|res://*/DataBase.ssdl|res://*/DataBase.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=81.211.69.78;initial catalog=Practice;persist security info=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlCeConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
      <parameters>
        <parameter value="System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0" />
      </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServerCompact.SqlCeProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServerCompact" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
  <system.data>
    <DbProviderFactories>
      <remove invariant="System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0" />
      <add name="Microsoft SQL Server Compact Data Provider 4.0" invariant="System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0" description=".NET Framework Data Provider for Microsoft SQL Server Compact" type="System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeProviderFactory, System.Data.SqlServerCe, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91" />
    </DbProviderFactories>
  </system.data>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Looks like this line `User user = null;` is the issue.

Comment: Which namespace `UserContext` is created?

Comment: `public int UserID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Password { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public string MiddleName { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }`

Comment: Does your web.config point to a different context? Paste the relevant web.config information into your question (not as a comment).

Comment: No, no other context, I added Web.Config

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have a mix of localdb and sql in your connection string. Try:

```
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="PracticeDB" connectionString="Data Source=81.211.69.78; Initial Catalog=Practice; Integrated Security=True; MultipleActiveResultSets=True;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
```